# `\pagebreak[n]` equivalent for multicols environment

Tags: multicol

Are there equivalent command for `\pagebreak[n]` for multicols environment? `\columnbreak` command only breaks the column, it does not have any option for demanding to a request for breaking column.

Comment: Should your last sentence end with "page"?

Comment: No, I want similar functionality for working with columns. (Of course, if column to be broken is the last column of the page, it is also a page break.)

Comment: `\pagebreak[2]` should work for giving column break hints

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately it did not work. Maybe a link to my code could be useful: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4b00

Comment: The normal use of `\pagebreak[n]` very rarely works either:-)

Comment: Don't link to an external site, every question benefits from a small complete test case edited in to a code block in the question